# ¿Qué declaraciones son necesarias para que las cookies me funcionen bien en Google Chrome?

Tags: php

Buen día.

Hasta ahora lo que se es que session_start(); debe estar al inicio, que hay que aceptar las cookies en el navegador y también he utilizado el caché para mantener las sesiones [session_cache_limiter('public');].

Alguien con más experiencia conoce todos los requerimientos? No se por qué se me pierden las sesiones.

Muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

la variable de sesión se pierde al cerrar el navegador.

Sino estás usando ningún framework prueba este código

```
function create_cookie() {
    setcookie('see_cookie', 1, time() + 300); //5min
}

/* * ******************************************************************************
 *                        Función para comprobar la cookie;
 * ******************************************************************************** */

function check_cookie() {

if (isset($_COOKIE['see_cookie'])) { //Si existe la renueva 5min
    setcookie('cont', $_COOKIE['see_cookie'] + 1, time() + 300);
    $active = 1;
} else {
    $active = 0; //No está activa.
}

return $active;
}


 create_cookie();
```

El check lo pondrías para renovarla si sigue dentro del tiempo sino lo echas.

```
  $active = check_cookie();

    if ($active == 0) {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['message'] = 'La sesión ha expirado';
        header("Location:Views/Disconnect.php");
    } else { blabla }
```

Comment: Gracias EduBw. Me generaste una duda... el framework es necesario para el funcionamiento de las sesiones? Cuál me recomiendas? Se instala en el hosting? Con lo que me has aportado no tendrían por qué eliminarse las sesiones? Soy nuevo en php. Disculpa mi ignorancia. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Un framework es una herramienta de trabajo para desarrollar una aplicación, al usar un framework cambian algunas cosas del propio lenguaje, sino lo estás usando porque estás aprendiendo ,vale no pasa nada, ya llegarás. para PHP mírate por ejemplo Laravel o Codeigniter.
Las sesiones son clases que las trae el propio lenguaje de PHP.
Se destruyen "automaticamente"cuando cierras el navegador pero la cookie se mantiene x tiempo porque se guarda en el cliente.

Comment: Muchas Gracias EduBw. ¿Cómo puedo trabajar con el framework en el hosting? el servidor me debe ofrecer el servicio? Trabajo sin framework. El asunto es que funciona normal localmente en todos los navegadores, pero en el hosting me falla con chrome.

Comment: Descargate xampp y dentro de la carpeta htdocs metes el archivo.php Si lo quieres subir a internet, tendrás que buscarte uno que se adapte a tus necesidades

Comment: Compa, me funciona perfecto local. Tengo un hosting en Host4Geeks, y ahí es donde me falla

Comment: Sabes qué declaraciones son necesarias para que funcionen bien las sesiones en el hosting? Muchas gracias

Comment: de igual modo,en tu hosting mételo en la carpeta htdocs, si tu host puede procesar PHP funcionará sino no.

Comment: Sabes qué declaraciones son necesarias para que funcionen bien las sesiones en un hosting? Muchas gracias

Comment: Además... el framework no se instala en el hosting, cierto? Host4Geeks me debe dar el soporte

Comment: Si la respuesta de las cookies funcionó marcalo en verde y crea una nueva pregunta para el hosting.

Comment: En realidad estoy en las mismas. Igual te agradezco mucho el interés